# How to use several XML datasources in report

Tags: java, xml, jasper-reports, datasource

I want to know if it's possible to have two XML datasources in JasperReports, one for the report, and the other for a subreport.

Comment: Please include the forum link with description of what you tried in order to help people understand where you're at with your efforts.

Comment: Hi, good idea, http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1007176/2-xml-datasources, but I don't think I'm in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use several XML datasources. With help of ***dataSourceExpression*** you can pass second (another) datasource to the subreport.

I'll show how to do it with help of *Java*. In case using *Java* code we don't need to specify the query (*XPath* expression) in report (main and subreport) with help of report's ***queryString*** property.

### The working sample

The main report and subreport will be used different *XML* files.

#### Datasources

The *customers.xml* file is a datasource for a main report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers>
    <id>ANTON</id>
    <id>AROUT</id>
    <id>BERGS</id>
    <id>BLAUS</id>
</Customers>
```

The *customers_details.xml* file is a datasource for a subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>ANTON</CustomerID>
        <CompanyName>Antonio Moreno Taquería</CompanyName>
        <ContactName>Antonio Moreno</ContactName>
        <ContactTitle>Owner</ContactTitle>
        <City>México D.F.</City>
        <Country>Mexico</Country>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>AROUT</CustomerID>
        <CompanyName>Around the Horn</CompanyName>
        <ContactName>Thomas Hardy</ContactName>
        <ContactTitle>Sales Representative</ContactTitle>
        <City>London</City>
        <Country>UK</Country>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>BERGS</CustomerID>
        <CompanyName>Berglunds snabbköp</CompanyName>
        <ContactName>Christina Berglund</ContactName>
        <ContactTitle>Order Administrator</ContactTitle>
        <City>Luleå</City>
        <Country>Sweden</Country>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>BLAUS</CustomerID>
        <CompanyName>Blauer See Delikatessen</CompanyName>
        <ContactName>Hanna Moos</ContactName>
        <ContactTitle>Sales Representative</ContactTitle>
        <City>Mannheim</City>
        <Country>Germany</Country>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

The data from two files related by Id (*Customers.id*=*Customers.Customer.CustomerID*).

This files contains some sort of compilation from sample *northwind.xml* file distributed with *JasperReports* library.

#### Master report's template

I used the *[JRXmlDataSource(String, String)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html#JRXmlDataSource(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))* constructor for passing *XML* datasource to the subreport. The subreport's depends on the main report's data in this sample.

The *XPath* expression for getting data in subreport is: `/Customers/Customer[CustomerID=<id>]`, where *`<id>`* is a value of *id* node from *customers.xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="master_with_xml" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="expression" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["/Customers/Customer[CustomerID='" + $F{id} + "']"]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="54" y="15" width="380" height="45"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource("customers_details.xml", $V{expression})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport_with_xml.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Subreport's template

The subreport is showing data for customer Id from master report (for each record).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subreport_with_xml" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CompanyName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ContactName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContactName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ContactTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContactTitle]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="City" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[City]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Country" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Country]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="75" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Company name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="200" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CompanyName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="15" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="15" width="200" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ContactName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact title:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="30" width="200" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ContactTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="45" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Country:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="45" width="200" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Country}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[City:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="60" width="200" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{City}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Java code

The *XPath* expression for getting data in main report is: `/Customers/*`.

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
try (InputStream inputStream = JRLoader.getResourceInputStream("master_with_xml.jrxml")) {
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream));
}

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.US);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JRXmlDataSource("customers.xml", "/Customers/*")); // select all customers with XPath
```

I've added *xalan* library to the classpath.

#### Output result

I've used the *PDFExporter* for generating this *pdf* file:

[image: The generated pdf file]

***Notes:***

1. The great sample of using *XML* datasource: *[XML Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xmldatasource/index.html#xmldatasource)*. The full code for this sample can be found at *demo/samples/xmldatasource/src* folder of *JasperReports library* distributive.
2. The good explanations of some features can be found in this posts: *[Looking for a working example of JasperStudio xml subdatasource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36368245/876298)*, *[JasperReports: JRDataSource.subDataSource shows undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27739982/876298)*
3. You can pass the datasource for the subreport via the main report's parameter.